# How to resolve stalled data transfer during 'sudo apt-get upgrade'?

Tags: networking, pi-zero-w, wireless, apt, update

My board is a Raspberry Pi Zero W. I have freshly installed Raspberry Pi OS Lite. *Release date: October 30th 2021, Kernel version: 5.10*

I have connected USB hub, mouse, keyboard, and monitor. The PSU is Apple 5.2V 2.4A wall wart adapter. I'm connected to wifi.

When I run "sudo apt-get update" it runs fine:

*Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease*
*Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease*

When I run "sudo apt-get upgrade" it runs fine initially and transfers data for various packages. But eventually the data transfer halts and I get "connection timed out" with download partially complete. This happens at different points in the transfer each time I try. (sometimes after 2 packages, sometimes after 10)

I suspect a network issue because no particular package consistently causes the errors. I have tried my home network and mobile hotspot but I get the same results.

As a Hail-Mary I ordered the official raspberry pi power supply, in case the errors are related to power supply fluctuations of my adapter, which I suspect is optimized for constant current charging.

Any idea what could cause these connection issues?

Comment: Don't use `apt-get` - it was never intended for the purpose. Use `apt` which is designed for interactive use.

Comment: If you want help you need to post actual error messages.